# When is Bialynicki-Birula decomposition a paving?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Suppose we have a smooth algebraic variety $X$ with an action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ with finitely many fixed points. Suppose $X$ can be covered by invariant quasi-affine open sets and suppose for each $x\in X$ the limit $\lambda x$ when $\lambda\to 0$ exists. Then Bialynicki-Birula proves that $X$ is a union of locally closed sets $W_i$ isomorphic to affine spaces.

I find often in the literature it is concluded that $X$ has a paving by affine spaces, but "paving" requires more: that $W_i$ are ordered in such a way that $\cup_{j \leq i} W_i$ is closed. But this issue is often ignored. Is there something I'm missing, for instance some general statement that would guarantee existence of such an ordering?

Comment: To get a paving, it is enough to assume that X admits a $\mathbb{C}^*$-equivariant embedding inside some projective space $\mathbb{P}(V)$ with linear $\mathbb{C}^*$-action. In my experience this is often enough to get what you want. If you want to be more fancy: it is enough for $X$ to admit an ample and $\mathbb{C}^*$-equivariant line bundle.

Comment: I agree that for projective varieties it is clear. I was wondering if there's some more general argument.

Comment: ahh OK. I have vague recollections of looking at the the relatively easy case of non-projective complete toric varieties (e.g. discussed in Fulton) and thinking it was a bit tricky. Other than that I have nothing to add.

Comment: I'd be very interested to hear if you do find something though...

Comment: There is an article "Filtrations of meromorphic $\mathbb{C}^*$-actions on complex manifolds" by Carrell and Sommese that is essentially about this question, but I am not sure if you would find their criteria useful (corollaries 1-4).

Answer (score 4):

Consider the partial ordering defined by
$$
i \le j
\qquad\text{if $\dim(W_i) \le \dim(W_j)$}.
$$
Since $\overline{W_i} \setminus W_i$ has dimension less than $W_i$ and is $\mathbb{C}^\times$-invariant, it is the union of some $W_j$ with $j < i$. Therefore,
$$
\bigcup_{j \le i} W_j = 
\bigcup_{j \le i} \overline{W_j}
$$
is closed.

Comment: @AntonMellit: where did I write $W_i \subset \overline{W_{i+1}}$?

Comment: @AntonMellit: I do not mean it is the union of all $W_j$ with $j < i$; I mean it is the union of some $W_j$ with $j < i$.

Comment: I see. I edited your answer to include "some". So everything would follow from this statement that it is the union of some $W_j$. Can you prove this statement?

Comment: Your claim is false, see "Białynicki-Birula, Some properties of the decompositions of algebraic varieties determined by actions of a torus. Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math. Astronom. Phys. 24 (1976), no. 9, 667–674", example 1. This is a blow up of $P^2$ with action with weights $(1,2,3)$ in the hyperbolic fixed point. The closure of a cell doesn't have to be a union of other cells. Your answer and its apparent popularity kind of confirms my complaint about the issue being ignored.